# what is the difference between form submission using ajax() method or by simply <form action="xyz" method="POST"> to servlet or php

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile, servlets

I am working on jquery mobile and using simple method for form submission to servlet but when i searched on google everyone is using ajax method for this , which method should i prefer and why.

Comment: You cannot use HTML to PUT or DELETE. You need to use ajax for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put simply, using 'ajax' doesn't cause a page refresh, so could result in a better user experience, lower data transfer usage (because you can just send a result like 'OK' or an error message rather than a full page), and cleaner code.  But if you want to have a complete refresh, there is no reason not to use the traditional form submission method.